# Comparing the function output type in assertion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai, jsdom

I'm struggling with writing a test assertion using chai, mocha, and JS-DOM. 
I have a simple function like:

```
function HtmlElement(el) {
  this.element = (el instanceof HTMLElement) ? el :document.createElement(el);
}
```

in the tests I have:

```
it('should have addClass method', function () {
  const ul = (new HtmlElement('ul'));
  ul.element.should.be.equals('<ul></ul>'); // Outputs the actual UL 
});
```

but the error:

```
AssertionError: expected <ul></ul> to equal '<ul></ul>'
```

is the one I can't understand - what type of the output is returned and what assertion should be used here ?

Comment: You're returning an object, and compare it to a string. When printing the error message the object is converted to a string, which happens to look identical, but it's not the same at all.

Comment: I see - so how can I match it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what deceze meant in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706993/comparing-the-function-output-type-in-assertion#comment96200091_54706993). In the test:

```
ul.element.should.be.equals('<ul></ul>');
```

`ul.element` is a JavaScript object. More precisely, it is a DOM node. However, `<ul></ul>` is a string. Chai does the comparison with `===`. If you compare a DOM node with something using `===`, the only thing that will return a true value is the *exact same DOM node*. "Exact same" means exact same JavaScript object. If you do:

```
const node = document.createElement("ul");
console.log(node === node);
```

You get `true` on the console. If you do this:

```
console.log(document.createElement("ul") === document.createElement("ul"));
```

You get `false` because the two operands are two different objects. For your purposes, the two DOM nodes may be "the same" but they are not the same as far as `===` is concerned. Since no string can be the same object as a DOM node, then your test fails. The error message may seem confusing, but that's because when JSDOM prints out the error, it serializes the DOM node. That is, then JSDOM prints out the DOM node, it really prints out the value of its `.outerHTML` property, and `.outerHTML` is the serialization of the node.

What you want to test for depends on what your ultimate aim is. If you want to test the structure of the element, you could check `.outerHTML`, something like:

```
ul.element.should.have.property("outerHTML").equal("<ul></ul>");
```

The title of your test is "should have addClass method"... so maybe you should be testing this:

```
ul.element.should.have.property("addClass").be.a("function");
```

If you meant to have that be a proxy for testing that you get an `HTMLElement`, I'd suggest doing this instead:

```
ul.element.should.be.instanceof(HTMLElement);
```

Comment: Thank you for this details explanation. It makes the picture crystal clear! I've also fixed my tests and the example is indeed to check the addClass method.